# Can all ordinals be obtained by taking successors and countable limits?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Define a class $K$ of ordinals inductively as follows:

- $0=\emptyset\in K$.
- For all $\alpha\in K$, the succesor of $\alpha$ is also an element of $K$.
- For every function $f\colon \mathbb N\to K$, the ordinal that immediately follows after all ordinals $f(0),f(1),\dots f(n),\dots$ is also an element of $K$.

Call an arbitrary ordinal $\beta$ fett iff $\beta\not\in K$.

**Question**. Do fett ordinals exist? In other words:

> Is there an ordinal $\beta$ such that $\beta$ is **not** an element of the class $K$?

Comment: I have to ask, where does the name "fett ordinal" come from?

Comment: "Fett" is a german word meaning something like "fat", "huge", "large" ...

Comment: Do you mind editing the title into something more informative? I have one vote up waiting for that to happen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such ordinals exist - for example, $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal.

The crucial issue here is *cofinality*: the cofinality of an ordinal $\alpha$ is the least $\beta$ such that there is a function $f:\beta\rightarrow\alpha$ whose range is unbounded in $\alpha$. It's easy to show that $K$ consists exactly of those ordinals of *countable cofinality* - that is, whose cofinality is $\omega$ - which are also not larger than any ordinal of uncountable cofinality.

Now, $\omega_1$ is *not* of countable cofinality, since the union of countably many countable sets is countable. So $\omega_1$ - and any larger ordinal - is not in $K$.

Comment: I'd say that you beat me to it, but clearly you didn't. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your answer took a few seconds longer because it's better (+1). Just my sour luck (say it fast) that I didn't see the question earlier. :P

Comment: It's not that. My cat is in the living room, freeing my to unleash the full might of my typing skills! :-)

Comment: If $K$ is defined inductively (i.e. as the intersection of all classes satisfying the three clauses), then $K = \omega_1$ rather than the class of ordinals of countable co-finality. No?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, note that the class of *all* the ordinals satisfies this definition. You want to say that $K$ is the smallest class of ordinals satisfying that the three requirements hold.

And I claim that at least under the axiom of choice $\omega_1$ is such a class of ordinals, and therefore $\omega_1$ is a Fett ordinal. It is in fact, the least Fett ordinal, therefore making it the Boba Fett of ordinals.

Let's see why.

1. $\varnothing\in\omega_1$, easy peasy.
2. If $\alpha\in\omega_1$, then $\alpha+1$ is also countable, so $\alpha+1\in\omega_1$ as well.
3. Finally, if $f\colon\Bbb N\to\omega_1$ is any function, then $\sup\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is the countable union of countable ordinals, therefore a countable ordinal. So we have all three requirements.

However, the axiom of choice is needed here. Not only that it is consistent that $\omega_1$ is not *not* a Fett ordinal without the axiom of choice, namely it *can* be the countable union of countable ordinals; it is possible that *every* ordinal is a successor or a countable union of smaller ordinals. In that case, no ordinal is a Fett ordinal.

So you need the axiom of choice to conclude the existence of Boba Fett.

Comment: That last line....  I laughed for a solid minute.  Thanks for making my day XD

Comment: Brevan, well, Star Wars happened in a long long time ago, in a galaxy far far away. Clearly it's not a constructive story!